# Why cant we use dev_kfree_skb() in interrupt context instead of dev_kfree_skb_irq()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

dev_kfree_skb() simply frees an skb.
Hence cant we use it to release an skb in interrupt context?
What's special about dev_kfree_skb_irq()